# Basic demonstration concerning the natural logarithm...

Tags: logarithms

Recently saw a question that asked me to show that $\ln\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right) = - \ln\left(\sqrt{2} + 1\right)$. How can I demonstrate that the LHS equals the RHS?

Comment: $-\ln x=\ln(1/x)$.

Comment: For natural log, it should be $\ln$ or $\log$.  Some use Ln, but certainly not In

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\log(\sqrt{2}-1) &= \log((\sqrt{2}-1)\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1}) \\
&= \log(\frac{2-1}{\sqrt{2}+1})) \\
&= \log((\sqrt{2}+1))^{-1}) \\
&= -\log(\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{align}

Comment: How did your mind even bring you to multiply inside the parentheses by (√2 + 1)/(√2 + 1)???

Comment: Not a problem, please accept the answer. 

Math, like most things in life, is a question of experience. I have the same reaction you just had day-in, day out, when I see people so clever it's frightening. That's good though, because it teaches you to embrace the feeling of confusion, and that's a supremely useful life-lesson. 

When driving you swerve out of the way of a cat, yet you barely notice a plastic bag. How did your mind even bring you to distinguish these two?